# Get the registry key of installed programs php

Tags: php, powershell, key, registry, wsh

I want to get a list of my installed programs.

I know how it works with powershell : `Get-ItemProperty HKLM:\Software\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\* | Select-Object DisplayName, DisplayVersion, Publisher, InstallDate | Format-Table –AutoSize .`

But I want it with php. Now I have this:

```
<?php
$Wshshell= new COM('WScript.Shell');
$data = $Wshshell->regRead('HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall');

?>
```

I get this error: ***Source:** WshShell.RegRead
**Description:** Unable to open registry key "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall" for reading*

Comment: Probably not the problem based on the error, but try using double backslashes. For example `"HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\\Software\\...`.

Comment: I have now this: $Wshshell= new COM('WScript.Shell');
$data = $Wshshell->regRead('HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\\Software\\Wow6432Node\\Microsoft\\Windows\\CurrentVersion\\Uninstall\\');
echo ($data);   it works, but it prints nothing

Comment: So the error is gone, but you don't see the values in `Uninstall`? How are you displaying them? I don't see anything that loops or echoes any data.

Comment: I use echo: echo $data);,

Comment: I doubt that will work, add this at the end - `var_dump($data->value);` - Do you see anything? You may need to loop over the results.

Comment: I have it done to converting the powershell command to json and display it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a project that allows PHP to obtain and interact dynamically with a real Powershell. Get it here: https://github.com/merlinthemagic/MTS

After downloading you would simply use the following code:

```
$shellObj    = \MTS\Factories::getDevices()->getLocalHost()->getShell('powershell');

$strCmd   = 'Get-ItemProperty HKLM:\Software\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\* | Select-Object DisplayName, DisplayVersion, Publisher, InstallDate';

$return1  = $shellObj->exeCmd($strCmd);

echo $return1;// list of all programs
```

You can issue any command you like against the $shellObj, the environment is maintained throughout the life of the PHP script.

Answer (score 0):

This can solve your problem:

```
$Wshshell = new COM('WScript.Shell');
$data = $Wshshell->regRead("HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\");

echo "result: " . $data;
```

You are doing correct but you looking for keys/values in the current selected folder, just add a trailing slash to get subfolders.

If you check registry there is no keys under the "Uninstall" Folder, but there must be sub-folders.

Comment: I want to get Display name of all subfolders in the uninstall folder

Answer (score 0):

in powershell you can read registry key like ths

```
Get-ItemProperty "hklm:\software\microsoft\windows\currentversion\uninstall\windows media player"
```